# Fail to iterate through collection returned

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have following program that fetches the data from DB and sends it to Main. I am able to iterate through the result in the function but not in Main.
Program is below :

```
  void Main()
{
    var data = GetAllCountry();
//  foreach( var t in data)
//  {
//    Console.WriteLine("{0}", t.country.ID); //fails here; says country not found
//  }

}

// Define other methods and classes here
  public IEnumerable GetAllCountry()
        {

                var countries = COUNTRY.Select(c => new
                {
                    country = new
                    {
                        ID = c.ID,
                        Description = c.DESCRIPTION,
                        CountryPhoneCode = c.COUNTRY_PHONE_CODE,
                        Currency = c.CURRENCY.CURRENCY_SYMBOL,

                    }
                });

                foreach( var t in countries)
                {
                  Console.WriteLine("{0}", t.country.ID);//works here and I am able to access t.country.ID here...
                }

                return countries;
            }
```

What wrong with this ? what are required modifications ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe as you are returning IEnumerable rather than IEnumerable`<T>`, it is not able to get the object type.

If you create a class for Country and the method returns IEnumerable`<Country>` it would work

```
public IEnumerable<Country> GetAllCountry()
        {

                var countries = COUNTRY.Select(c => new
                {
                    country = new Country
                    {
                        ID = c.ID,
                        Description = c.DESCRIPTION,
                        CountryPhoneCode = c.COUNTRY_PHONE_CODE,
                        Currency = c.CURRENCY.CURRENCY_SYMBOL,

                    }
                });

                foreach( var t in countries)
                {
                  Console.WriteLine("{0}", t.country.ID);//works here and I am able to access t.country.ID here...
                }

                return countries;
            }
```